# The compiler shoots itself in the foot when trying to optimise/inline my trivially looking but non-trivial dtor, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, destructor, shared-ptr, pimpl-idiom

I have this shared pimpl*. It forward declares the implementation object and has a custom-implemented shared pointer object to implement the pimpl idiom (again, with sharing semantics). Condensed, it looks like this:

#### Foo.h

```
#include "SharedPtr.h"

class Foo_impl;
class FooFactory;
class Foo {
  friend class FooFactory;
  private:
    SharedPtr<Foo_impl> pimpl;
    Foo(SharedPtr<Foo_impl>);
  public:
    ~Foo();
};
struct FooFactory {
  Foo build() const;
};
```

#### Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

Foo FooFactory::build() const {
  return Foo(SharedPtr<Foo_impl>(new Foo_impl(/*...*/)));
}
Foo::Foo(SharedPtr<Foo_impl> pimpl)
  : pimpl(pimpl) {
}
Foo::~Foo() {
}
```

Now, (I think) the compiler gets really smart when compiling `Bar.cpp` (which uses `Foo` objects and *other* `SharedPtr` objects) and complains:

```
SharedPtr.h: In member function ‘void Deallocator<T>::operator()(T*) const [with T = Foo_impl]’:
SharedPtr.h:54:   instantiated from ‘void SharedPtr<T, Delete>::drop() [with T = Foo_impl, Delete = Deallocator<Foo_impl>]’
SharedPtr.h:68:   instantiated from ‘SharedPtr<T, Delete>::~SharedPtr() [with T = Foo_impl, Delete = Deallocator<Foo_impl>]’
SharedPtr.h:44: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator:
SharedPtr.h:42: warning: ‘t’ has incomplete type
Foo.h:29: warning: forward declaration of ‘struct Foo_impl’
SharedPtr.h:44: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined.
```

Who could possibly be calling `~SharedPtr<Foo_impl>` other than `Foo` and `FooFactory`? Where does that come from and how can I fix it?

Note: Making `~Foo` virtual doesn't help, which is even more puzzling to me.

---

<sub>* The fact that the impl is shared is irrelevant here, I just want to prevent the typical "please define a copy-ctor/assignment method" comments. It is fully intentional that the pimpl pointer is shared.</sub>

---

Edit: The `SharedPtr` interface:

```
 33     template <typename T> struct Deallocator {
 34       private:
 35         bool doDelete; // not const to be def. assignable
 36       public:
 38         Deallocator(bool doDelete = true) : doDelete(doDelete) {}
 39         bool willDelete() const {
 40           return doDelete;
 41         }
 42         void operator()(T* t) const {
 43           if (doDelete)
 44             delete t;
 45         }
 46     };
 47
 48     template <typename T, typename Delete = Deallocator<T> > class SharedPtr : private SharedPtrBase {
 49       private:
 50         Delete del;
 51         T* ptr;
 52         void drop() {
 53           if (ptr && shouldDelete()) {
 54             del(ptr);
 55           }
 56           ptr = NULL;
 57           leave();
 58         }
 59       public:
 60         // SharedPtr(p,false) will not delete the pointer! Useful for Stackobjects!
 61         explicit SharedPtr(T* ptr = NULL, Delete del = Delete())
 62           : SharedPtrBase(), del(del), ptr(ptr) {
 63         }
 64         SharedPtr(SharedPtr const& from)
 65           : SharedPtrBase(from), del(from.del), ptr(from.ptr) {
 66         }
 67         ~SharedPtr() {
 68           drop();
 69         }
 70         SharedPtr& operator=(SharedPtr const& from) {
 71           if (&from != this) {
 72             drop();
 73             del = from.del;
 74             ptr = from.ptr;
 75             join(&from);
 76           }
 77           return *this;
 78         }
 79         SharedPtr& operator=(T* from) {
 80           return *this = SharedPtr(from,del);
 81         }
 ...
```

Comment: What is `SharedPtr`? Surely not `std::shared_ptr`...

Comment: @ildjarn: It's a project-specific custom shared pointer type. `Deallocator` is also a custom `delete` wrapper.

Comment: And you don't think its implementation might be pertinent to your question..?

Comment: Please post the definition of `SharedPtr`. It is likely that it requires the template parameter to be a complete type in its assignment operator.

Comment: @ildjarn: I don't see why, it works essentially like `std::shared_ptr` other than having an `explicit` ctor. But I'll add the implementation of `Deallocator` -- I guess that could be useful.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` can work with incomplete types, your `SharedPtr` clearly does not.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, ildjarn: I added the relevant parts of the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't declare an assignment operator for `Foo` so if you use it the compiler will define one for you. The compiler generated one will use then copy assignment operator of `SharedPtr` which, through a number of intermediate functions, calls `delete` on a `Foo_impl`.

I can't see your `Bar.cpp` so I can't say where you might be copying a `Foo`.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. I now defined a custom destruction object (so it wont use the default `Deallocator`), but your explanation helps me understand where the original problem came from. Didn't see it.